# Using ExpandoObject when property names are dynamic, is this possible?

Tags: c#, dynamic, expandoobject

I need to create an object that has properties that are named dynamically like:

```
<users>
  <user1name>john</user1name>
  <user2name>max</user2name>
  <user3name>asdf</user3name>
</users>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: (The proposed duplicate wasn't a duplicate, as it didn't involve ExpandoObject.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. Just use it as an `IDictionary<string, object>` to populate:

```
IDictionary<string, object> expando = new ExpandoObject();
expando["foo"] = "bar";

dynamic d = expando;
Console.WriteLine(d.foo); // bar
```

In your XML case, you'd loop over the elements, e.g.

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(file);
IDictionary<string, object> expando = new ExpandoObject();
foreach (var element in doc.Root.Elements())
{
    expando[element.Name.LocalName] = (string) element;
}
```

Comment: Great, as an addition, how can I create a list of these?  So in your example, I would want to add expando to a list of expando's.  I'm getting an error saying I can't add a IDictionary to a expandoobject.

Comment: @cool: So cast back to ExpandoObject. If that doesn't work, ask a new question with details.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: In the above response, if there exists elements with the same name and value, ExpandoObject return an error : Same Name Value already exists in Objects... 
What could be the solution for allowing repeat name/ value in expando Objects...
refer question Link

Comment: @Jon Skeet : Above Question Link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53649959/allow-same-name-value-for-dynamic-json-creation-using-expandoobject-and-idiction